# Jquery and retrieving object via .find()

Tags: javascript, jquery

Via ajax method, I need to fetch an html which is a real mess, half of the elemnts are opened but not closed.

Now I need to find  elements which contains time string as in such format: "19:00-20:00" which means it should have something such as "HH:MM-HH:MM".

How can I fetch these rows that contains such time-time elements ?

an example for ajax call source can be found here: http://www.tatlisestv.com/YayinAkisi.asp?Day=3 
I am interested with start-end time and the nearest right  element that holds the program name for that hour interval.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

```
$(strong).filter(function() {
return /(\d{2}:\d{2}-?){2}/.test($(this).text());
});
```

should work (not tested)